# in angular 15 how to set base href via ng serve?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a scenario where I am redirecting HTTP traffic from my cluster to my local machine, and when I do this I need the base attribute in the index file set to a path, so the Index.html should look like

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ukcustoms</title>
  <base href="/web/mypath/">
  ... other stuff
  
</html>
```

Now in angular you used to be able to do this via ng serve

> ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --port 4203 --base-href
> /web/mypath/

In fact the --base-href param still works well in ng build, which works fine for my cluster version of the code.

Can anyone tell me whether there is still a way to do this via ng serve as well?

The things I have tried have all resulted in an Index file which has a base of "/"

**What I have tried**

- editing the index.html file to include the path
- adding APP_BASE_HREF to the ngModule

Answer (score 0):

Insert this line into your `tsconfig.json`, Angular checks for the baseUrl in the tsconfig file:

```
{
  ...,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "baseUrl": "/web/mypath/",
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my code won't compile if I make this change

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `baseHref` property in your `angular.json` file - or if you're using an NX mono-repo with Angular like I am, in the application's `project.json`.

To set it for your production builds, add it to the `build.configurations.production` object.

For local development, add it to the `build.configurations.development` object.